# Root LinearLayout doesn't make dialog fullscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-dialog, android-relativelayout

Here is my code for showing a custom fullscreen dialog.
My problem is when the root view of Dialog is `LinearLayout`, the dialog is not fullscreen but if it is `RelativeLayout` then dialog fullscreen

```
public void showDialog(Context context){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_increase_repeattime);
        dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           ...
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```

[image]

Here is dialog layout xml using `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffffff">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="OK"
        android:id="@+id/btn_dialog"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Using `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffffff">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="OK"
        android:id="@+id/btn_dialog"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why this happened? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the problem but you didn't set the orientation for your Linear Layout. Try adding `android:orientation="vertical"` to it.

Comment: change the height of parent layout to android:layout_height="match_parent" ... i is working...